# many-to-many string comparison

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to write a predicate similar to

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY manyNames in %@", allNames];
```

but instead of 'in' I need 'like'

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY manyNames like %@", allNames];
```

This causes an error.

So I want to get results with some objects of manyNames, which are similiar to at least one of allNames.

Comment: This has a `like` example https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by joining the strings and making one string of them, then looking for that.